# I'm a high school student working on the report for an experiment. I was told to do a two-way ANOVA, followed by Tukey's HSD Test but I'm stuck

Tags: anova, biostatistics

Same context however: So I'm trying to see the effect of 2 different types of essential oils (rosemary and ginger) on e.coli. What I did was that I increased the concentrations of the oils and I used the disk diffusion tests and measured the inhibition zones formed.

Based on the following results, how am I meant to carry out a two-way anova. What calculator/software should I typically use? I've seen a lot and they somehow differ? I also don't understand how to structure my table in a proper way in order to use the tool to analyze it. Is there a specific structure to follow or can I just input this table exactly the way it is?
[image]

Comment: Short answer to your ultimate question: No, Excel is not the right tool.  Use statistical software.